# Cloud build service account permission to build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, terraform-provider-gcp

I have my env set as Cloud build app (Github app) to provision terraform through cloud build 
to Google Cloud Platform. The build is a simple cloud composer with cloud functions, that creates these resources along with the right service accounts and members. 
However, only the owner permission can execute this successfully, I want to have least privilege for the cloud build service account. I have used a lot of roles and nothing seems to be successful. i.e. create service account, editor, access context manager admin, access approval approver. When I run the build via github commit, I receive this error other than having the owner set as role

> Error: Error applying IAM policy for cloudfunctions cloudfunction
>   googleapi: Error 403: Permission
>
> Error: Batch "iam-project-redacted modifyIamPolicy" for request
>   "Create IAM Members roles/composer.worker
>   serviceAccount:composer-env-account@redacted.iam.gserviceaccount.com
>   for \"project \\"redacted\\"\"" returned error: Error applying IAM
>   policy for project "redacted": Error setting IAM policy for project
>   "redacted": googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission,
>   forbidden. To debug individual requests, try disabling batching:
>   https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/guides/provider_reference.html#enable_batching

Is there a IAM policy/role that allows for service accounts to successfully build through cloud build?

With Owner role set to cloudbuild service account, everything build successfully

Answer (score 2):

The Cloud Build service account has assigned by default the Cloud Build Service Account role which has the permissions [referred here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud-build-roles). Notice that you'll only be limited to perform the [following tasks](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/set-service-account-permissions#what_is_the_service_account): which include doing the pertinent activities in order to make a build successful (accessing Cloud Source Repository, Cloud Storage and Container Registry).

Along with the Cloud Build Service Account role, you'll need to [grant additional roles](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/set-service-account-permissions#granting_additional_access) depending on what else you are doing with Cloud Build.

In the particular case of your error message you'll need to add the [Cloud Functions Developer role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud-functions-roles) in order to be able to get full access to Cloud Functions. The whole procedure is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/testing/test-cicd).

There are similar roles if you are also deploying to App Engine, or managing Google Kubernetes Engine, etc. Find all the list of available roles [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles).

Comment: Thank Daniel, I have come across making additional custom roles to execute this pipeline to the cloud build service account. A lot of trial and error and testing and finding correct least privilege permission that are able to build but none the less. Was successful.